# How to sort json data alphabetically in java without external library?

Tags: java, android, json

**I have the following json:**

```
       {"attendance_data":
{"date":"26-Sep-2013","users":
[{"uid":"2","status":"present","name":"xyz"},
    {"uid":"3","status":"present","name":"mno"},
    {"uid":"4","status":"present","name":"cde "}
    ,{"uid":"5","status":"present","name":"wxy"}]}}
```

**I want to sort it alphabetically like:**

```
 {"attendance_data":{"date":"26-Sep-2013","users":
[{"uid":"2","status":"present","name":"cde"},
    {"uid":"3","status":"present","name":"mno"},
    {"uid":"4","status":"present","name":"wxy "},
    {"uid":"5","status":"present","name":"xyz"}]}}
```

**is it possible without external library?**

Comment: Why without a lib? It is a HW like thing or you just want to train parsing?

Comment: Looking at your code would this not change uid? cde used to be 4 now you change him to 2? Is that what you want?

Comment: I mean why don't you use a library for parsing JSON, I'm pretty sure there are useful libraries for that purpose

Comment: not uid i want to sort only name object.

Comment: @joey.enfield means uids are changing when you're sorting in your example. Do you need to change uids or want that first item to get lowest uid?

Comment: why would you want to do that ? json is a vector, you are not really supposed to do anything with it.

Comment: uid doesn't matter , i just want to sort "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load JSONArray to ListArray with custom object contains your variables, sort it and than create JSONArray from list. This is little walk around, but will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Java itself has some classes to handle json. Look at [JSONObject.java](http://json.org/java/) and the stuff around. You can just pass a String into the contrustor of the object. It also provides methods to get other json objects within the jasonobject. Also json arrays and all supported datatypes.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json in a JSONObject, then get your JSONArray "users" and cast that object to a `List <User>`.

Then order the list with a custom comparator for your user and then go back!

( Sorry for no code but I'm on my phone)